# Veracode scan for java

Tags: veracode

```
SecurityWrapperResponse secResWrap = new SecurityWrapperResponse(response);
secResWrap.addHeader("", "Base64EncodingString");
```

above line I am getting "Improper Neutralization of CRLF Sequences in HTTP Headers ('HTTP Response Splitting')" for veracode scan

any one have idea please help me out.

Answer (score 1):

I've found that any raw string used in this sort of sensitive area will trigger this sort of response from a Veracode static scan. You can use ESAPI for Java to encode strings in a way that Veracode is happy with. https://www.owasp.org/index.php/Category:OWASP_Enterprise_Security_API
They also say:

> You can use or modify ESAPI however you want, even include it in
>   commercial products.